# Is there a more thread safe variable available in JMeter to get() and set() variables?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

With more aggressive load, I have noticed that 2 or more threads set the exact same variable values, thus causing subsequent requests that use said values to fail. I'm using a JSR223 PostProcessor where I have the following code:

```
URL url = new URL(vars.get("response_url"));
String path = url.getFile();
vars.put("request_path", path);
```

Upon inspection of requests, I have seen that sometimes one thread set "request_path" to "example1" and another thread set that variable to the exact same value. I do not want to decrease number of threads or ramp up time; that is not an option.

Is there a more thread safe variable than "vars" to use when getting/setting variables in JMeter? Or is there another way to prevent this?

Comment: Hello, any feedback on answer ? If ok please accept and upvote so that other users can trust it , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vars is specific to 1 thread (so no need for thread safety here) so in core jmeter what you describe cannot happen.

If this is happening with some 3rd party plugin, you should report a bug to the project.

Try making a thread dump when issue occurs to see what is happening

Answer (score 0):

As per [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) article *vars* stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance which in its turn belongs to [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html)

If you look into [JMeterContextService](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v5_1_1/src/core/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContextService.java#L28) class source you will see that JMeterContext is declared as [ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) and [Thread-Local Storage Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage) implies that the variables are not accessible by other threads.

So I would recommend checking where does this `${response_url}` come from using i.e. [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) or [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property as most probably the issues is not connected with using `vars` shorthand from Groovy code (you are [using Groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223), aren't you?)